Taking the Differentials of $u = x+y$
To solve $\int_{}^{}\cos(x+y)dx$ by substitution, we use $u = x+y$ to get $\int_{}^{}\cos(u)du = \sin(u) = \sin(x+y)$. This means that $du = dx$, my question is why? How do we take the differentials from $u = x+y$ to get $du = dx$, where does the $y$ term go?
Thanks in advance

Is there a reason not to think $y$ is a constant?

$du=dx$ is just a convenient way to express $du/dx=1$, which is true for constant $y$

Because the integral ends with $dx$, the dummy variable here is $x$. As others have explained in comments, this means $y$ is not a "term" as such (it is a constant term, but I don't think that is what you meant) and therefore $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ so when we calculate $\frac{du}{dx}$ we are finding $\frac{d}{dx}(x+constant)=1$.
